# SSRS 2008, attempting to hide columns with a parameter and hide rows made blank by hiding columns

Tags: reporting-services

So, i've figured out how to hide a column based on a report parameter.  I also know how to hide a row based on a lack of values.  [MSDN article on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220590.aspx)

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to hide a row that is blank if the columns containing data are hidden by parameter.

An example:

```
+-------+-----+-------+-------+----+------+
| User  | Zip | Zorba | Queen | Of | Mars |
+-------+-----+-------+-------+----+------+
| User1 |  34 |       |     3 |  8 |      |
| User2 |   9 |    39 |    85 |    |      |
| User3 |     |       |    43 |  2 |    2 |
+-------+-----+-------+-------+----+------+
```

Lets say I hide the last three columns with my handy report parameter.  Now what's displayed to the user is a blank row for User3.  But in the dataset, its not blank.  So the row visibility I have set won't work.

What I found when searching was all about how to hide a row or column, which I can do.  This seems to require more knowledge than I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested `IIF` to get desired result. You can read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms157328.aspx

You can hide the row using the expression. In that expression you can check for the column hiding value to verify if row is to show or hide

```
 = IIF(Youroldexpressiontohidetherow, true,IIF(yourexpressiontohidecolumn,true,false))
```

So, If your row hiding expression returns false due to it has values in last three columns then you can check whether you are hiding the last 3 columns if you are the set to true if yo are not then set to true. 
Hope it helps. In case of issue comment.