# I want to insert three columns runtime(dynamically) in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Usually we design the table to have x number of rows and y number of columns in a report. But how can we create a report which adds the rows and columns dynamically at run time based on the result of the stored procedure?

For example, student A has sponsored student sdf and student B has sponsored two student as shown in below table. So, I need to add dynamically new member name (nm_name) and new member id (nm_id) columns in matrix or in table.

```
+-------+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
| St_id | Name| nm_id | nm_name |nm_id  | nm_nme|
+-------+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
|1      |  a  |   5   |    sd   |  8    | fgf   |
|2      |  b  |   39  |   bgj   |       |       |
|3      |  c  |   78  |   fhf   |  2    |    2  |
+-------+-----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
```

I want above report layout in SSRS.

Comment: Please show some data and what output do you expecting ?

Comment: Add this info in question with proper formatting and as your question mentions `shown in below table` there is no table in your question

Comment: There is no direct way to dynamically generate columns in SSRS but there are hacks which you can use if you provide details I can give you that answer

Comment: How can i share you table? It is not allowing me to share table.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280800/ssrs-2008-attempting-to-hide-columns-with-a-parameter-and-hide-rows-made-blank/27289558#27289558 and see how the example data and expected details explained and try to update your question with your details

Comment: Std_id   std_name  nm_id  nm_name  these are header columns of my table and need to add dynamically nm_id and nm_name in table.

Comment: You can add some dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your explanation is that you want to add the 3 columns dynamically, But `SSRS` doesn't allow adding the column at the `runtime` for that you can use the trick as below,

```
  1) Add three(whatever number of columns you need) extra columns in your existing matrix 
  2) Then set there visibility expression depending upon when you want to show the columns 
  3) As You mention that if sponsored by some other student then show the column so your expression can be 

  = IIF(Fields!studentsponserd.value ,False,True)
```

This way you can set the visibility of the columns and this will be visible according to your expression condition. 
AS I am not sure what is your particular condition I am not able to give you the correct expression. The expression might need to tweek as per your need. 
You can see [this blog for more.](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.in/2010/10/displaying-dynamic-columns-in-ssrs.html)

Comment: If this answer helps you please accept it so question will be closed